# How to ouput JSON in javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to print the results of a json object from a php query into javascript.
So basically the query results looks like:

```
{"points":
[{"lat":40.766696929932,"long":-73.990615844727},  
{"lat":40.688514709473,"long":-73.96475982666},
{"lat":40.714504241943,"long":-74.005630493164},  
{"lat":40.704719543457,"long":-74.009262084961},    
{"lat":40.693260192871,"long":-73.968894958496},     
{"lat":40.760955810547,"long":-73.967247009277},

]}
```

When i try to get the php variable (using AJAX) containing the json object i get:
**VM62:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**
I tried googling to see how the error relates to my code but i still don't get it.
Can someone explain to me how to get the json in javascript?

```
<?php
$connect = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=datab user=thomas password=iamtom") or die("Could not connect: ");
$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT geometry FROM table");
if (!$result){
    echo '{"error":"no results"}';
}

$points= array();    
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $coordinate = json_decode($row['geometry'])->coordinates;
    $p = new stdClass;
    $p->lat = $c_2[0];
    $p->long = $c_1[1]; 
    array_push($points, $p);
}
$output = new stdClass;
$output->points = $points;
echo json_encode($output);
pg_close($connect);
?>
```

Here is my HTML/JS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "dab.php",
    data: {
        sataVariable: "here is some data send with GET method"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var j = JSON.parse(data);
        document.writeln(data);   // attempting to take the coordinates and store it in a variable
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the content type header of your PHP script to: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`? (*at the top of your php script*)

Comment: hey mate, i still get the uncaught error

Comment: What do you get if you check your network tab and see the actual response being returned by your request?

Comment: in the network tab, i see the json i.e points:[{lat...lng..}].

Comment: can you check the `console.log(typeof(data))` before ` var j = JSON.parse(data);` and make sure it's not `Object` if it's object you neednot do `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @ThomasC What is "$output" printing in your PHP code??

Comment: okay mate so it's of type object. How do i read the data then?

Comment: @ThomasC is $output printing the JSON object?

Comment: @HenryDev it prints out the json i.e with json_encode(), without that i recieve a Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: if the the type is output just use `var j = data;` instead of `var j = JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're feeding `dataType: "JSON"` into your call to [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the data retrieved from the AJAX call is automatically being parsed from JSON to a JavaScript object (though I'd switch `"JSON"` to `"json"` to match the documentation):

> `"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

Don't manually parse the response again using `JSON.parse()` in your success handler; just work directly with `data`.

Now that you have your data in a JavaScript object called `data` you can interact with it, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.points[i].lat, data.points[i].long);
}
```

Comment: hey mate, thanks for the answer. I followed your instructions and well i tried to print the data. document.writeln(data) in hopes i would at least see the json but all i get as an output on the page is [object Object]. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: How are you "outputting" the results?  try console.log(data)' and see what you get in your browser console.  Sounds like you may need to learn how to work with JavaScript objects...

Comment: @ThomasC, that means you have a JavaScript object. What is your actual end goal for this data? I'd be surprised if you literally want to dump it out to the browser.

Comment: @Chris ultimately i want to plot these lat/lng on a map.  it would be outrageous if i just print all those points on the screen for nothing!

Comment: @ThomasC, you've got the data into a JavaScript object. Now you can start working with it. I've added an example to my answer that should print out all of the `lat` and `long` values to the browser's console. You could put that in your `success` handler, for example.